# React Native Fetch Blob/React Native Blob Util Fail in Production but not in Developer time

Tags: react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I am trying to download a pdf generated through an own api that worked normally for me until yesterday, since then it has stopped working without any modification. Reviewing in developer mode through the metro everything seems to work correctly without any problems (I download the pdf normally), but when deploying the application in the playstore it closes unexpectedly, leaving me without knowing why this happens.
First I was using the React Native Fetch Blob, then I used React Native Blob Util hoping it would solve the problem but it keeps happening. Do you guys have any ideas for why does this happen?
The PDF file download this function:

```
   const generarReciboPdf = async (datosDeuda:FormularioScreenParams,formaPago:ReactText,nroCheque?:string) =>{
    const{config,fs} = ReactNativeBlobUtil
    if (formaPago === 4 && (nroCheque == ""|| undefined)) {
      return console.log('debe llenar todos los campos');
      
    }
    const { DownloadDir } = fs.dirs;
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    let datosDeudaCompleto= {
      ...datosDeuda,
      forma_pago:formaPago,
      nro_cheque:nroCheque
    }

    let url = 'https://sys.arco.com.py/api/appRecibos/generarReciboPdf/'+JSON.stringify(datosDeudaCompleto)
    
    // return console.log(url);
    
    const options = {
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        useDownloadManager: true, // true will use native manager and be shown on notification bar.
        notification: true,
        mime:'application/pdf',
        path: `${DownloadDir}/recibo_${datosDeuda.mes_deuda.replace(/ /g, "")}_${datosDeuda.razon_social.replace(/ /g, "")}.pdf`,
        description: 'Downloading.',
      },
    };
    config(options).fetch('GET', url,{Authorization :'Bearer '+token}).then((res) => {
      console.log('se imprimio correctamte el pdf');
      setErrorPdf(1)
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
      setErrorPdf(-1);
    });

}
```

Also, this error appears in Play Console: "PlayConsole Error Image".
[PlayConsole Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvsu5.png)

Comment: Have you found the solution?